# Overriding an abstract set accessor with a readonly member variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Given the following snippet of TypeScript:

```
abstract class Foo {
    public abstract get x(): number;
    public abstract set x(value: number);
}

class FooImpl extends Foo {
    public readonly x: number = 42;
}

const foo: Foo = new FooImpl();
foo.x = 5;
```

I was wondering why tsc doesn't complain that `FooImpl`'s `x` member variable is marked `readonly`. (At least there is no complaint in tsc v. 3.3.1 nor in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.9.2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgYge2wg3gFAIkIAOAriMgJawKiQzwIDmApogB4AUAlAC4EAOwoBbEOygBuYqUrU6DcNDiIwnBLwBuwZBXZDREqX1kBfQoRRoMObAEkxZZAnZcI7YQBM7uAnIkCrT0UOzA3tjCyACeWkbiklAIALwIACwATBZWsFGQCABmuEL2qSLsAO5YuE4u-LLF2AB0XOUArNJAA), which runs v. 3.9.2 at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you've cast it to `Foo`, which clearly does allow that value to be set.

(The fact the class is `abstract` doesn't matter here, since that only prevents instantiation via `new Foo()`)

If you leave off that cast, it does error like you expect:

```
const foo = new FooImpl();
foo.x = 5; // Cannot assign to 'x' because it is a read-only property.(2540)
```

But if you cast an instance to a parent class, that will always be allowed, since that is how inheritance should work. And if the child class *changes* one the properties of the parent class, typescript can't really keep track of that, because you've told it to be a type that is before that change.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I suppose I should have left those final two lines out. I am more wondering why TypeScript accepts `FooImpl` as a valid implementation of `Foo` when it doesn't seem to implement `Foo`'s `public abstract set x(value: number);`

Comment: Well, that's actually a good question. I'd also argue that it shouldn't be a valid implementation of the abstract class.